# How to check a css propert is supported?

Tags: css

Is there anyway to check if a given CSS property is supported? For example, I want to do an animation on a page using `perspective-origin`, but if not available I would just alter the size instead.

Comment: Use [Modernizr](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/)

Comment: @JohnConde, just make that the answer. The article explains both the library and the code behind it. Perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many css-hacks for browsers but for that you need to handle yourself each css property for all browsers

[CSS Hacks](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

but if you want automatically handled all the browser for CSS3 and html5 then use [Modernizr](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/)

**Supported browsers**

It support IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.6+, Safari 2+, Chrome. On mobile, support iOS's mobile Safari, Android's WebKit browser, Opera Mobile, Firefox Mobile.

Comment: The first link refers to “Conditional Comments”, which really do not address the problem at all. Regarding Modernizr, I think you should primarily link to http://modernizr.com and specify exactly how it helps to solve the specific problem presented. That would be an example using `csstransforms3d`, I presume. Modernizr does not really detect support to individual properties but to sets of properties (or “modules” in a loose sense).

Answer (score 0):

Use http://caniuse.com/ website to check how your property is supported by different versions of web-browsers. You can load different styles according to client's browser version.

Also, you can emulate not-supported properties in old browsers by using CSS3PIE (http://css3pie.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can include modernizr.js which will be helpful for your issue.

you may visit the following link which was helpful when i was learning about it.

http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/126-using-modernizr/